# Access an element in a Multidimensional (3D and 4D) array

Tags: python, arrays, database, multidimensional-array, extract

I have the following problem: I have a matlab database (.mat) with structure 4x17x4 and 5 fields. The fields inside are "field_a", "field_b", "field_c", "field_d", "field_e". In matlab is quite easy to extract an element from it but I need to find a solution in python. In matlab I do this:

```
data = {database(:,1,1).a}
```

How can I extract "data" in python?
What I have done by now is to load matlab database in python:

```
fnameSISO["States"] = sio.loadmat('databaseSISO_states')
```

But when I try to extract data it doesn´t work:

```
data = fnameSISO["States"][:,1,1]
```

Furthermore I tried to load the database with:

```
fnameSISO["Loo"] = np.asarray(sio.loadmat('databaseSISO_states'))
```

It doesn´t work either.

What can I do in this situation? If I save the database in a json file will I be able to extract the elements I need?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please add some data that one can test your code with?

Comment: hi, thanks for your interest but I can´t really share the actual data I am using. I will think about a workaround :)

Comment: You say it doesn't work, what does that mean? Are there error messages, do you get wrong data? You are being far too vague...

Comment: @Florin-CatalinGrec: You can create random data with the same (or similar) structure to your data.  Any solution will be highly dependent on both the structure of the data and the exact problem it causes.  So we really need example data and the specific problem (including line numbers if it is an exception) you are having.

Comment: hi guys, thank you for your interest in this problem. I found the issue: I was not using enough indexes to extract the info. I should have done something like   data = fname["States"]["database"]["field_a"][:,1,1]. I didn´t go deep enough. Sorry for being very vague but it´s only because of the data I am handling it.

Comment: If you found the issue, please write an answer and accept it so people know this problem is solved.

Comment: @sobek I already wrote the solution:  data = fname["States"]["database"]["field_a"][:,1,1]   I didn´t extract correctly :)

Comment: Yes, but you wrote it in a comment. The proper way is to post in in an answer so when other people face the same issue and land here, they immediately see the solution without having to go through 5 comments.

Comment: @sobek - thanks, I am new and didn´t know which is the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I did a mistake when writing the syntax. 
Solution:

```
data = fname["States"]["database"]["field_a"][:,1,1]
```